# Non commutative derivatives in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to compute the derivatives of some non-commutative fields squared.

```
phi = function("\phi",commutative=False)(x)
diff(phi*phi,x)
```

However, instead of getting something like

[image], it returned

[image: $$ $$]

What am I doing wrong?

In order to get a correct solution I had to define to different fields [image: $$]  and do the computation as a product of those two different fields.

Comment: I don't know to make the equations appear correctly

Comment: This is probably a bug. Best to open a github issue: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues